# Novels with chapters annotated POV

Tags: data-request, english, corpora, books

I'm looking for one or more novels, that multiple characters points of view.
(I don't care if it is 3rd person or 1st person), 
with each chapter (or paragraph) annotated as to which character's POV it is from.

A good example of a in-copyright work is George R.R. Martin's Song of Ice and Fire. It has over a dozen POVs and each chapter it titled with the name of the character.

I'm sure these exist as there are many many books out of copyright.
But I have no idea how to work out which match my criteria.

---

The purpose of this is to investigate a machine learning approach to POV detection, [as in this question.](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/1018/sort-select-chapters-paragraphs-by-pov)

Comment: What is kind of similar is Hansard records of parliamentary speech, which is annotated with speaker.

Comment: Every [epistolar novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistolary_novel#Later_works) looks appropriate.

Comment: This is true. If there is a way of getting a list of epistolar novels from guttenburge or wiki source etc than that is a solid answer right there.

Comment: Wikidata allows to get only this list only: http://tinyurl.com/y6u2d9cf :(